# How to select from table only rows that a value from field 1 are paired with at least two different values of field 2

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table:

```
select * 
from
    (values 
        (1,'a','alex'),
        (2,'b','joe'),
        (3,'b','alex'),
        (4,'c','joe'),
        (5,'a','alex'),
        (6,'d','cloe')
    )as mytable (key_field,field1,field2)
```

I need a query that will bring the rows with keys 2 and 3.

The logic is as follows:

1. For every value in field1, build a list of all values from field1, and for each value build a list for all values it had appeared together with from field2, so in our case it would be:

   ```
   {a : alex, b: joe, alex, c: joe, d: cloe}
   ```
2. Go over all the lists for each field1 value and check if there are more then 1 item

   ```
   b : joe, alex
   ```
3. Return unique keys for the raws that had such field 1 values.

   ```
   2,3
   ```

I understand it as a code, but I don't know how to write a sql query that gives me this result?

*************** Solved By Yogesh Sharma ***************

I paste the full solution query for any reference

I added 1 more layer to the problem: 
The Query need to return from stage 2 only pairs that contain a given name.

Example the below dataset with the given name to be 'cloe' shall return only rows 4,9.
If the given name is 'alex', query shall return only raws 2,3

```
declare @field2Compulasory as char(16)
set @field2Compulasory = 'cloe'
;
with  CTE1 as
(
    select * 
    from
        (values 
            (1,'a','alex'),
            (2,'b','joe'),
            (3,'b','alex'),
            (4,'c','joe'),
            (5,'a','alex'),
            (6,'d','cloe'),
            (8,'e','bill'),
            (9,'c','cloe'),
            (10,'g','jenifer'),
            (11,'h','fred')
        )as mytable (key_field,field1,field2)
), 
CTE2 as (
select *
from CTE1 as t
where exists    (
                    select t1.field1 
                    from CTE1 as t1 
                    where 1=1 
                        and t1.field1 = t.field1 
                        and t1.field2 <> t.field2               
                )
)
select *
from CTE2 as t
where exists    (
                    select *
                    from CTE2 as t1
                    where 1=1
                        and t1.field1 = t.field1
                        and t1.field2 = @field2Compulasory
                )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample data suggests me `EXISTS` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.field1 = t.field1 and t1.field2 <> t.field2);
```

Comment: thank you, I indeed was looking for a solution employing the exists statement. However I believe a with statement is required, otherwise it seems that 't' table is not recognized in the sub-query (I was receiving Invalid object name 'mytable').
Using `with` statement your solution worked great

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT key_field
FROM (
    VALUES (1,'a','alex')
                    ,(2,'b','joe')
                    ,(3,'b','alex')
                    ,(4,'c','joe')
                    ,(5,'a','alex')
                    ,(6,'d','cloe')
    ) AS t1(key_field, field1, field2)
WHERE [field1] + ':' + STUFF((
            SELECT DISTINCT ',' + field2
            FROM (
                VALUES (1,'a','alex')
                    ,(2,'b','joe')
                    ,(3,'b','alex')
                    ,(4,'c','joe')
                    ,(5,'a','alex')
                    ,(6,'d','cloe')
                ) AS t2(key_field, field1, field2)
            WHERE t1.field1 = t2.field1
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') LIKE '%,%'
```

Explanation:

1st I am grouping by column `field1` and bring a ***distinct*** set of `field2` with comma separated value

key_field   field1  Column2
1           a       a:alex
2           b       b:alex,joe
3           b       b:alex,joe
4           c       c:joe
5           a       a:alex
6           d       d:cloe

Then I am checking if any of rows in column2 have **,** which gives me the final answer.

i.e.

```
2,3
```